# Split on newline, but not newline-space in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, split

I am trying to split my string into an array on every new line, but not if a newline begins with a space.

```
ORGANIZER;organizer@example.com //YES
ATTENDEE; user@example.com, another@exa //YES
 mple.com, peter@example.com //NO
DESCRIPTION;LANGUAGE=en-US //YES
```

Comment: Please add what you have so far, and what it is you're cant get to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you REALLY want this?

```js
const str = `ORGANIZER;organizer@example.com
ATTENDEE; user@example.com, another@exa
 mple.com, peter@example.com
DESCRIPTION;LANGUAGE=en-US`
console.log(str.replace(/\r?\n /g,"").split("\n"))
```

Comment: You're a hero! That's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4):

This looks like you could use a regex for your split :

```js
let values = `ORGANIZER;organizer@example.com
ATTENDEE; user@example.com, another@exa
 mple.com, peter@example.com
DESCRIPTION;LANGUAGE=en-US`;

console.log(values.split(/\n(?!\ )/));
```

Here, we are using a negative lookahead `?!` to make sure there is no space after the `\n`

**P.S.** we would appreciate if you try before asking.